# Fancybox 3 - Add buttons to custom HTML popup

Tags: html, fancybox-3

I'm using fancybox 3, something like this

```html
<a href="#popup" data-fancybox="popup" data-buttons="['slideShow','fullScreen','thumbs','share']">Click me!</a>

<div id="popup">MY POPUP with custom HTML</div>
```

However, no buttons get added, and I get a jQuery error "Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in ['slideShow','fullScreen','thumbs','share']". I've tried passing an object of options through data-options, but that did not work well. What is the correct syntax for what I am trying to do? I want to add some of the standard buttons, like the thumbnails preview, share button (if that's possible with custom HTML), etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use correct JSON syntax, e.g., replace ` and ":

```
<a href="https://source.unsplash.com/xAgvgQpYsf4/1500x1000" data-fancybox="group" data-buttons='["slideShow","fullScreen","thumbs","share"]'>
  <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/xAgvgQpYsf4/240x160" />
</a>
```

Demo - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oEaoVr?editors=1000

Comment: Actually, I don't seem to be able to get this to work. It works in your demo because you link to an image, but it doesn't work when I link to custom HTML on the same page.

Comment: Then maybe try this - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WMLXzb?editors=1000 (this does not seem to work for current version; you will have to wait for v3.3 or you could grab source code from the codepen)

Comment: Nice! Any clue when that version is coming out? I'd rather wait until the official release.